# Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of generalized Weyl algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, weyl-algebra

I believe that the Gelfand-Kirillov (GK) dimension for a generalized Weyl algebra $D(\sigma,a)$ is just the GKdim$(D) + 1$.

Does anyone have a reference for this?

I can find partial results, and I am sure this is implied by more general results regarding GK dimension, but I would like to have a precise reference for generalized Weyl algebras.

Comment: What is GK Dimension?

Comment: @ThiKu Gelfand-Kirillov dimension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Kirillov_dimension

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in the section "GK Dimension" of [Ebrahim - The prime spectrum and representation theory of the 2×2 reflection equation algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05369).

If the automorphism $\sigma$ is locally algebraic, then indeed $\operatorname{GKdim}(D(\sigma,a))=\operatorname{GKdim}(D)+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in [Zhao, Mo, and Zhang - Gelfand–Kirillov dimension of generalized Weyl algebras](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00927872.2018.1444169), Lemma 3.2.

Comment: As the editor tells you, you should enter a link description when you include a link.  I have edited in this case.